# Detect matching parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there an easy way to detect if a string has any of the three following combinations?:

```
...( ... ) ...
...[ ... ] ...
...< ... > ...
```

ie, does it contain a pair of matching parentheses, square or angle brackets?
I can do it as 3 separate Regex statements.  Can it be reduced to one?

Comment: Sounds similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Use your regex with `..|..|..`

Comment: What should it return for `((((((((...)))`?

Comment: @thg435. Probably `$&$%%#@#@FT%^%N *&#` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/\([^[\]<>]*\)|\[[^()<>]\]*|\<[^[\]()]*\>/.test(str);
```

In an easier way to see:

```
/
    \(
        [
            ^[\]<>
        ]*
\)
|
\[
    [
        ^()<>
    ]
\]*
|
\<
    [
        ^[\]()
    ]*
\>
/
```

Comment: Are there regex syntax highlighters? I want to try to understand how this works